# Can not apply prop:procedure in typed racket

Tags: structure, racket, typed-racket

When defining a struct in typed racket I can no longer use the `prop:procedure`. In normal racket I can do something like:

```
(struct profile-unit (a t c g)
    #:property prop:procedure (thunk* 12))

(define t (profile-unit .1 .1 .2 .6))
(t)
> 12
```

But when I try it in typed/racket I get a type check error:

```
(struct profile-unit ([a : Real] [t : Real] [c : Real] [g : Real])
  #:property prop:procedure (thunk* 12))
(t)
> Type Checker: Cannot apply expression of type profile-unit, since it is not a function type in: (t)
```

Is there another way of defining this property in typed racket?

Comment: No longer as in it worked in `#lang typed/racket` before?

Comment: `thunk*` also doesn't typecheck in Typed Racket for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Leif Andersen said, the `#:property` struct option doesn't work in typed racket.

However for the special case of `prop:procedure`, you can use the [`define-struct/exec`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._define-struct%2Fexec%29%29) form.

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-struct/exec profile-unit ([a : Real] [t : Real] [c : Real] [g : Real])
  [(λ (this) 12) : (profile-unit -> Any)])

(define t (profile-unit .1 .1 .2 .6))
(t) ; 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Structs in `typed/racket` cannot have the any `#:property` fields. They also don't support generics.

The fact that you can even call it like this looks like a bug to me.

If you really do want to call the struct like a function though, you can do it by defining it in untyped code, using [`require/typed`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=require%2Ftyped#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._require%2Ftyped%29%29) an `#:struct` to get it into typed code, and using [`cast`](https://cs2500.ccs.neu.edu:7978/;((%22k%22%20.%20%22(3%206%2027190760)%22))?tag=hw3%2Fz%2Fa%2Bb.zip;mode=download) to turn it into a procedure. For example:

```
#lang typed/racket

(module foo racket
  (provide (struct-out profile-unit)
           make-profile-unit)

  (struct profile-unit (a t c g)
    #:property prop:procedure (thunk* 12))
  (define make-profile-unit profile-unit)
  ((profile-unit 1 2 3 4)))

(require/typed 'foo
               [#:struct profile-unit ([a : Real]
                                       [t : Real]
                                       [c : Real]
                                       [g : Real])])

((cast (profile-unit 1 2 3 4) (-> Any)))
```

In this example, `profile-unit` is being called as a procedure.